# When I put @Consumes and @Produces in post or get?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I know @Consumes and @Produces accept type when method excute. Example :  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE  or consumes =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

But I have a question that @Consumes annotations should be placed in GetMapping, Put Mapping or PostMapping. Similar to the remaining annotations: @Produces .

Comment: It would seem relelvant to only declare `@Consumes` on APIs that expect a request body, things like POST and PUT. A GET request does not have a request body, so `@Consumes` is meaningless.

Comment: Sometime I look in Post method it declare both  `@Consumes` and `@Produces`. It correct ?

Comment: Yes, of course this is correct. Just like a method declares both input parameter types and return types.

Comment: Yes, you should declare both. Unless, of course, the POST method does not have a response body (e.g. 204 No Content). Not that it hurts to have both for every method, generally `@Consumes` and `@Produces` is declared at the class level to avoid redundancy.

Comment: You're mixing Spring with JAX-RS. They are not the same thing and are not compatible. `@Consumes/@Produces` are JAX-RS and `@PostMapping/@GetMapping` are Spring.

Answer (score 1):

@Consumes and @Produces simply tell what media type the HTTP method takes in and returns. so maybe your HTTP method comsumes and produces a media type value, why not use both. in my opinion you should always use both. mostly at class level, so any other method that consumes or produces a different media type value would explictly override the class level annotation and also you wouldn't have to start declaring @Produces or @Consumes for every method in the class, which often to me is a code smell.

Comment: What happens if you put different media type in a GET request that only consumes JSON? does the HTTP request fail? I'm trying to understand what is the point of these "produces/consumes"